# Path to access file with php

Tags: php, apache, sqlite, path, server

I have my files into `/var/www` but i need access sqlite file into folder 
`/home/my/words`

I'm trying do this:

```
$dir = 'sqlite:../../home/my/words/bd.sqlite';
```

But path doesn't work.

**Error**:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file' in /var/www/db.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/db.php(20): PDO->__construct('sqlite:..\..\ho...') #1 /var/www/Details.php(14): require_once('/var/www/db.php') #2 /var/www/controller/Controller.php(14): require_once('/var/www/Detail...') #3 /var/www/index.php(5): require_once('/var/www/contro...')

If i use, for example: `$dir = 'sqlite:test\db.sqlite';` it works great.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing to understand the error is always read the error. Have you activate error reporting? (`error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` at top of your script); have you checked Apache error logs? Probably www don't have right privileges for `../../home/my/words`

Comment: Path doesn't work as in...? You don't have the rights to access the file? It's not the good file? It doesn't load? It returns an error code? Anyway, you could use the absolute path instead of a relative one, e.g. `$dir = 'sqlite:/home/my/words/bd.sqlite';`.

Comment: I have error reporting enabled. :)
**My code:**
`$dir = 'sqlite:..\..\home\my\words\db.sqlite';`

**Error:**
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file' in /var/www/db.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/db.php(20): PDO->__construct('sqlite:..\\..\\ho...') #1 /var/www/Details.php(14): require_once('/var/www/db.php') #2 /var/www/controller/Controller.php(14): require_once('/var/www/Detail...') #3 /var/www/index.php(5): require_once('/var/www/contro...') `

If i use, for example: 
`$dir = 'sqlite:test\db.sqlite';`

Works great.

Comment: @fusion3k My files are in `var/www` folder, and i wanna access `home/my/words` folder.
You can see all folders here:  ![List Folder](http://i.imgur.com/8akvaBo.png)

Comment: Thanks all. Problem with permissions in folder words and file db.sqlite.